# How to make a string accept an Excel error- runtime error 13- mismatch

Tags: vba, for-loop, mismatch

I am trying to format downloaded data and then insert into SQL. The nature of the data is such that there will be errors such as #NAME?, #N/A Invalid Field etc. I have a variable of data type string which takes the value of a new cell each time a for loop is run. The loop crashes due to a mismatch error occuring when the loop hits a data point with an error in it (found out my message boxing the loop).

Why can a string not accept an error as its value for the string? I have seen a post about this and the recommended answer was to use If IsError but I need the  '#N/A' part of the error as to identify that one has occured, rather than skip the row. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :) An Extract of the code is below:

```
'Insert static fields
Dim field As String

        code = "'" & tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 1) & "'"
        For j = 2 To 48

            MsgBox (tbl.DataBodyRange(i, j))
            field = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, j).Value
            'Recursively going through each cell

            If InStr(field, "#N") <> 0 Then
                field = "NULL "
                k = 1
```

It hits the error at the messagebox first, the message box will display the mismatch error.

Comment: check to see if the cell has an error using isError: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/iserror-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around the problem is to use the VARIANT data type to deal with the error.

As you've found out a STRING variable can't hold an error value, while the VARIANT can.  You can then use code along the lines of:

```
IF ISERROR(field) THEN
   field = NULL  
   K=1  
END IF
```

A VARIANT can also hold a NULL value.

**Edit:**

> I have seen a post about this and the recommended answer was to use
>   If IsError but I need the '#N/A' part of the error as to identify that
>   one has occured, rather than skip the row.

The `ISERROR` part identifies that an error has occurred.  This line of code on its own won't skip the row; it gives you an opportunity to do something else with the row such as replace the error value with a NULL value or some other required value.